# tikz graphs: draw an edge from a node without a goal node

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

Is it possible to write an edge going from a node but out into nowhere, see image below (ignore the trace of goal node that is visible)

[image]

Comment: If you are doing diagrams like this, you may be interested in the `tikz-cd` package.

Comment: What is the difference between the two packages? is tikz-cd a subset of tikz ?

Comment: [`tikz-cd`](http://ftp.eq.uc.pt/software/TeX/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf) is a bunch of macros which use tikz. i.e. the arrow you want to do would be written like `\arrow[loop above]{}{1}` inside a `tikzcd` environment.

Comment: [tikz-cd](http://ftp.eq.uc.pt/software/TeX/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf) is a bunch of macros which use tikz. i.e. the arrow you want to do would be written like `\arrow[loop above]{}{1}` inside a `tikzcd` environment. The only problem is that I don't know how to make the circles, that's why I don't write an answer.

Comment: @Manuel : `tikz-cd` is designed for commutative diagrams. While you can probably tweak it to draw graphs or automata, tikz libraries such as `automata` are probably more suitable for this purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like `\draw[->] (node) --++(0:2cm) node[above,midway]{0};` or `\draw[->] (node) --++(2cm,0) node[above,midway]{0};` ?

Comment: Nice! Is it possible to get the arrowhead too?

Comment: @Parham: I'm not sure to understand your comment, `\draw[->]` means draw a line with an arrowhead at the end. If you don't see the arrowhead with this command, may be it's better that you edit your question and include a minimal 'not' working example.

Comment: Nevermind, a typo was the culprit. Thanks though!

Comment: @Parham: Your welcome!

Answer (score 6):

For automata drawings, you can also use the tikz library `automata`.

It doesn't really bring anything new for your example, but if you try to extend it to a real automaton, it may prove easier to use that syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[state,initial by arrow, initial text={}] (s) {$b_{0}b_{1}$};
  \path[->] (s) edge[loop above] node {1} ();
  \path[->] (s) edge node[above] {0} +(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note that if you don't need the label above the right arrow, you can use a similar syntax to `initial...`, that is :

```
accepting by arrow, accepting text={}
```

[image]